# Can't provide public access to my mashup in Fi-Ware

Tags: fiware-orion

I've put a tick to public in embed and I've taken the iframe. I provided this access to another person in other PC. Mashup is loaded correctly but the map doesn't show the POI's, for example. Nothing appears on that.

Through Firebug I can see 403 forbidden error when doing POST request or NGSI connections. What's the problem?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the POST request (URL, headers and payload) that is being responsed with 403 forbidden, please?

Answer (score 1):

Orion Context Broker doesn't response with 403 Forbidden natively, so I guess that probably some component between the client and Orion (such as [a PEP proxy](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Authorization)) may be causing that response.